# Using power series to solve non-homogeneous differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I've been stuck on this for a while. I've got the following non-homogeneous differential equation and I have to give a solution in the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nX^n$: 
$$
y'' - 2y'x^2 + 4xy = x^2 + 2x + 2
$$
Could you please go step by step? I really need to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general procedure. Where are you up to?

1. Write down power series for $y'$ and $y''$
2. Substitute those expressions into the left-hand side of the equation
3. Equate both sides of the equation by equating the coefficients of all powers of $x$
4. Solve the system of equations in the $c_n$

Comment: Do I need to manipulate the equation at all before starting to sub in the power series?

Comment: I don't see why you would, no.

Comment: So after I finish doing the stuff for the left hand side, I'm a little confused what I would do after in terms of equating both sides of the equation by equating the coefficient of all powers of x?

Comment: Two power series in $x$ are equal if and only if the coefficients of all powers of $x$ are equal: * the constant terms are equal * the coefficients of $x$ are equal * the coefficients of $x^2$ are equal, etc. I'm sure there are worked examples in your lecture notes and text book

Comment: No, we've only dealt with homogeneous ones involving power series

Comment: The principle is the same. You just need to muster your courage and do the calculation. I suggest you look at $c_0, ..., c_6$ first. It will give you a sense of what's going on. And you should be able to identify a recursive relationship.